# Merit of specific community wikis

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Should we add a couple of specific wikis for these?  I get asked for "a good list for..." these things all the time.

- Camping list (luxury/car camping)
- Backpacking list
- Ultralight Backpacking list

Answer (score 3):

I think such topics can be covered by Great Question (with Great Answers, of course), which would itself be linked in the **FAQ** section.

They are really frequently asked questions: fast check in google keyword tool returned 18.000 searches for phrase `Backpacking list` monthly.